# Timer job removing web part after 5 minutes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, 2013, timer-jobs, variations

I have 3 lists on my home page.

- News
- Events
- Alerts

I have 2 sites

- English(Master site)
- Arabic

I have added News, Events and Alerts web parts on English home page. News and Events are displaying fine but there is problem with Alerts.

After every 5 minutes, when I refresh page, SharePoint removes it from home page. Looks like some timer job which updates/propagates pages between variations is doing this but I don't know why!

So let's say if I add Alerts on English home page and after 5 minutes if I refresh page, it is gone. Then I have to add it again and after 5 minutes it's gone again.

What's going on?

Comment: O_o Weird. Anything that gets caught in the SharePoint log when the web part gets deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correct, when using variation sites SharePoint sync the sites so they are identical. If something is missing in one variation site it will be removed from all variation sites.

If you have webparts which should only be available for one language group, try and see if you can use audience instead.

Comment: Looks like there was some problem with the web part zone in that page where that web part was being displayed. I deleted that web part zone, added a new one and now it is working fine.